# Cable Management

Tags: desk, cables, cable-management

I have a **** tonne of wires behind my monitor. As my room is too damn small, I am using chest of drawers as a table for my desktop PC. The "table" has no holes at the back to feed any cables through, nor can I thread them around because it's back is glued to the wall. Obviously I can't leave them lying on the floor because that's an instant trip hazard.

How can I tidy these cables up? Any tips and tricks?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to home improvement as defined in the scope of the [faq]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Cable Spiral Wrap

Try something like this [Spiral Wrap](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B016045XH4). Not a perfect solution, but if you have a few cables that are essentially together - e.g., video + power + audio + USB webcam - then you can wrap them all together so that they are still accessible but will be less of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

You might try Velcro or hook & loop straps which you can either buy as a [roll](https://www.lowes.com/pd/VELCRO-0-75-in-Black-Strap-Fastener/1087893) or find stamped into individual straps.